# Getting `Failed to list *v1beta1.IngressClass: ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io` error with Traefikv2.3

Tags: ibm-cloud, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress

I'm trying to use `Traefik Kubernetes Ingress`. I'm using `traefik:v2.3`. K8's cli version is `v1.18.3` and server version is `v1.18.6IKS`. I'm using IBM Kubernetes services to deploy this. But I'm getting below errors in pod logs. I'm following [offical link](https://docs.traefik.io/master/routing/providers/kubernetes-ingress/)

**complete Logs**

```
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=info msg="Configuration loaded from flags."
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=info msg="Traefik version 2.3.0-rc2 built on 2020-07-15T20:22:27Z"
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=debug msg="Static configuration loaded {\"global\":{\"checkNewVersion\":true},\"serversTransport\":{\"maxIdleConnsPerHost\":200},\"entryPoints\":{\"web\":{\"address\":\":80\",\"transport\":{\"lifeCycle\":{\"graceTimeOut\":10000000000},\"respondingTimeouts\":{\"idleTimeout\":180000000000}},\"forwardedHeaders\":{},\"http\":{\"redirections\":{\"entryPoint\":{\"to\":\"websecure\",\"scheme\":\"https\",\"permanent\":true,\"priority\":2147483647}}}},\"websecure\":{\"address\":\":443\",\"transport\":{\"lifeCycle\":{\"graceTimeOut\":10000000000},\"respondingTimeouts\":{\"idleTimeout\":180000000000}},\"forwardedHeaders\":{},\"http\":{}}},\"providers\":{\"providersThrottleDuration\":2000000000,\"kubernetesIngress\":{}},\"log\":{\"level\":\"DEBUG\",\"format\":\"common\"},\"accessLog\":{\"format\":\"common\",\"filters\":{},\"fields\":{\"defaultMode\":\"keep\",\"headers\":{\"defaultMode\":\"drop\"}}},\"certificatesResolvers\":{\"letsencrypt\":{\"acme\":{\"email\":\"prayagsingh003@gmail.com\",\"caServer\":\"https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\",\"storage\":\"/data/acme.json\",\"keyType\":\"RSA4096\",\"tlsChallenge\":{}}}}}"
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=info msg="\nStats collection is disabled.\nHelp us improve Traefik by turning this feature on :)\nMore details on: https://docs.traefik.io/contributing/data-collection/\n"
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *ingress.Provider {}"
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=debug msg="Using Ingress label selector: \"\"" providerName=kubernetes
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=info msg="ingress label selector is: \"\"" providerName=kubernetes
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=info msg="Creating in-cluster Provider client" providerName=kubernetes
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *traefik.Provider {}"
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider internal: {\"http\":{\"routers\":{\"web-to-websecure\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"web\"],\"middlewares\":[\"redirect-web-to-websecure\"],\"service\":\"noop@internal\",\"rule\":\"HostRegexp(`{host:.+}`)\",\"priority\":2147483647}},\"services\":{\"noop\":{}},\"middlewares\":{\"redirect-web-to-websecure\":{\"redirectScheme\":{\"scheme\":\"https\",\"port\":\"443\",\"permanent\":true}}}},\"tcp\":{},\"tls\":{}}" providerName=internal
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *acme.Provider {\"email\":\"prayagsingh003@gmail.com\",\"caServer\":\"https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\",\"storage\":\"/data/acme.json\",\"keyType\":\"RSA4096\",\"tlsChallenge\":{},\"ResolverName\":\"letsencrypt\",\"store\":{},\"ChallengeStore\":{}}"
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=info msg="Testing certificate renew..." providerName=letsencrypt.acme
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware noop@internal" entryPointName=web routerName=web-to-websecure@internal middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider letsencrypt.acme: {\"http\":{},\"tls\":{}}" providerName=letsencrypt.acme
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal middlewareType=RedirectScheme routerName=web-to-websecure@internal entryPointName=web
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=debug msg="Setting up redirection to https 443" middlewareType=RedirectScheme routerName=web-to-websecure@internal entryPointName=web middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" entryPointName=web routerName=web-to-websecure@internal middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=web middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery middlewareType=Recovery
time="2020-07-26T17:01:04Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one"
E0726 17:01:04.892814       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1beta1.IngressClass: ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressclasses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
E0726 17:01:04.896024       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1beta1.IngressClass: ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressclasses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
time="2020-07-26T17:01:05Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware noop@internal" routerName=web-to-websecure@internal entryPointName=web middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder
time="2020-07-26T17:01:05Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" routerName=web-to-websecure@internal middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal middlewareType=RedirectScheme entryPointName=web
time="2020-07-26T17:01:05Z" level=debug msg="Setting up redirection to https 443" routerName=web-to-websecure@internal middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal middlewareType=RedirectScheme entryPointName=web
time="2020-07-26T17:01:05Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" entryPointName=web routerName=web-to-websecure@internal middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal
time="2020-07-26T17:01:05Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery middlewareType=Recovery entryPointName=web
time="2020-07-26T17:01:05Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one"
E0726 17:01:08.006765       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1beta1.IngressClass: ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressclasses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
E0726 17:01:12.311744       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1beta1.IngressClass: ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressclasses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
E0726 17:01:23.452737       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1beta1.IngressClass: ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressclasses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
E0726 17:01:39.526007       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1beta1.IngressClass: ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressclasses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
E0726 17:02:16.043578       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1beta1.IngressClass: ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressclasses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
```

**RBAC**

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - services
      - endpoints
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update

---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: traefik-ingress-controller
    namespace: default
```

**Traefik Ingress**

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: myingress
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: websecure
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls.certresolver: letsencrypt
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls.domains.0.main: traefik.example.in
spec:
  rules:
    - host: traefik.example.in
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: traefik
              servicePort: 8080
```

**Deployment Traefik**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: traefik-ingress-controller

---
### Deploy Traefik to a Cluster ###
## We can use Deployment, DaemonSet or Helm Chart
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: traefik
  labels:
    app: traefik
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traefik
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        operator: Exists
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - name: traefik
        image: traefik:v2.3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        resources:
            limits:
              memory: 400Mi
              cpu: 400m
            requests:
              memory: 400Mi
              cpu: 400m
        args:
        - --log=true
        - --log.level=DEBUG
        - --accesslog
        #- --providers.kubernetescrd # use this when using IngressRoute
        - --providers.kubernetesingress # use this when using Ingress
        - --entryPoints.web.address=:80
        # - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
        # - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
        - --entryPoints.websecure.address=:443
        - --certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.caServer=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
        - --certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.tlsChallenge
        - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=myemail@gmail.com
        - --certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/data/acme.json        
        ports:
        - name: web
          containerPort: 80
        - name: admin
          containerPort: 8080
        - name: websecure
          containerPort: 443  
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
            add:
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /data
            name: storage-volume    

      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: storage-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: traefik-acme-storage
```

**Service Traefik**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: traefik
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      name: web
      targetPort: 80
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      name: admin
      targetPort: 8080
```

Please help. I'm new to `Kubernetes`. I'm already using `Traefik` with `docker-swarm` but there's a lot difference how we use `Traefik` with `K8s` and with `docker`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try this in your ClusterRole:

```
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io
    resources:
      - ingresses
      - ingressclasses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
```

instead of your

```
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Doc, Now I switched to CRD's and also using `cert-manager` for HA.