# How to fix "Failed to watch *v1beta1.IngressClass: failed to list *v1beta1.IngressClass: ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, haproxy-ingress

I have HA proxy ingress in Kubernetes AKS. After upgrading Kubernetes version, I get errors from HA proxy. I tried to solve the problem modifying my old `haproxy.yaml` to avoid deprecated API's and to get the latest image of HA proxy ingress. But the error persist. How can I fix the errors?.

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63208754/4540020), but it doesn't work for me.

I checked [this issue](https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress/issues/714) on github, but despite I use v0.12-snapshot.3 the error persist.

This is my modified haproxy.yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: ingress-controller
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: ingress-controller
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - endpoints
      - nodes
      - pods
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - services
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - "extensions"
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - events
    verbs:
      - create
      - patch
  - apiGroups:
      - "extensions"
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: ingress-controller
  namespace: default
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - pods
      - secrets
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
    verbs:
      - get
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
    verbs:
      - create
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - endpoints
    verbs:
      - get
      - create
      - update
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ingress-controller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ingress-controller
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-controller
    namespace: default
  - apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: User
    name: ingress-controller
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ingress-controller
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: ingress-controller
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-controller
    namespace: default
  - apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: User
    name: ingress-controller
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: ingress-default-backend
  name: ingress-default-backend
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: ingress-default-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: ingress-default-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ingress-default-backend
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/defaultbackend:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-default-backend
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
  selector:
    run: ingress-default-backend
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: haproxy-ingress
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: haproxy-ingress
  name: haproxy-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: haproxy-ingress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: haproxy-ingress
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: ingress-controller
      containers:
      - name: haproxy-ingress
        image: quay.io/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress:v0.12.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "75m"
          limits:
            memory: "256Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        args:
        - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-default-backend
        - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/haproxy-ingress
        - --reload-strategy=reusesocket
        ports:
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
        - name: stat
          containerPort: 1936
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10253
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: haproxy-ingress
  name: haproxy-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
  - name: stat
    port: 1936
  selector:
    run: haproxy-ingress
```

The following is the output of kubectl logs :

```
I0307 20:52:16.873675       6 launch.go:215]
Name:       HAProxy
Release:    v0.12-snapshot.3
Build:      git-b34edd0
Repository: https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress
I0307 20:52:16.873776       6 launch.go:218] watching for ingress resources with 'kubernetes.io/ingress.class' annotation: haproxy
I0307 20:52:16.873787       6 launch.go:225] watching for ingress resources with IngressClass' controller name: haproxy-ingress.github.io/controller
I0307 20:52:16.873802       6 launch.go:230] ignoring ingress resources without any class reference - --watch-ingress-without-class is false
I0307 20:52:16.873968       6 launch.go:492] Creating API client for https://10.0.0.1:443
I0307 20:52:16.902520       6 launch.go:504] Running in Kubernetes Cluster version v1.17 (v1.17.16) - git (clean) commit d88fadbd65c5e8bde22630d251766a634c7613b0 - platform linux/amd64
I0307 20:52:16.908078       6 launch.go:257] validated default/ingress-default-backend as the default backend
I0307 20:52:18.693995       6 listers.go:134] loading object cache...
E0307 20:52:18.696953       6 reflector.go:127] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1beta1.IngressClass: failed to list *v1beta1.IngressClass: ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressclasses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
E0307 20:52:19.982962       6 reflector.go:127] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1beta1.IngressClass: failed to list *v1beta1.IngressClass: ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressclasses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
E0307 20:52:23.089836       6 reflector.go:127] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1beta1.IngressClass: failed to list *v1beta1.IngressClass: ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressclasses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
E0307 20:52:28.419408       6 reflector.go:127] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1beta1.IngressClass: failed to list *v1beta1.IngressClass: ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressclasses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
E0307 20:52:37.624105       6 reflector.go:127] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1beta1.IngressClass: failed to list *v1beta1.IngressClass: ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressclasses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
I0307 20:52:45.320562       6 main.go:47] Shutting down with signal terminated
I0307 20:52:45.320631       6 controller.go:208] shutting down controller queues
E0307 20:52:45.320675       6 listers.go:132] initial cache sync has timed out or shutdown has requested
I0307 20:52:45.320711       6 controller.go:87] HAProxy Ingress successfully initialized
I0307 20:52:45.320722       6 main.go:40] Exiting (0)
```

Comment: You need to add `networking.k8s.io` wherever you see `extensions`. See an example [here](https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress/blob/1fa4c33db32ca495513650b6a43d3723eb4d589c/docs/haproxy-ingress.yaml#L43). Line 60 has another one. You also need to add `- ingressclasses` below `- ingress` as well. The static file is not being updated, I strongly recomment you to generate a new one with helm, see the [getting started guide](https://haproxy-ingress.github.io/docs/getting-started/).

Comment: @JoaoMorais, thank you. I changed haproxy.yaml to mimic helm chart templates. it didn't worked, then I deleted old haproxy ingress, installed it using helm. It didn't worked either. I upgraded kubernetes to version 1.18.4 from 1.17, uninstalled haproxy ingress, then installed it again and alleluia!, it worked at the end.

Comment: Hello, since you found the solution, could you please add it as an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

As per @jesús-lópez comment, upgrading the kubernetes version to `1.18.4` from `1.17` and reinstalling `haproxy` resolved the issue.